# Finding the amount of rows and columns for a 2-D array in C++

Tags: c++, sizeof, multidimensional-array

I know in C++ you can get a arrays amount of rows and columns with:

```
 int rows = sizeof array / sizeof array[0];
 int cols = sizeof array[0] / sizeof array[0][0];
```

However is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Yes. Since this is `C++` use `vector`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++11 you can do this using template argument deduction. It seems that the [`extent`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/extent/) `type_trait` already exists for this purpose:

```
#include <type_traits>
// ...
int rows = std::extent<decltype(array), 0>::value;
int cols = std::extent<decltype(array), 1>::value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [sizeof()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) function;

```
int rows =  sizeof (animals) / sizeof (animals[0]);
int cols = sizeof (animals[0]) / sizeof (string);
```

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void sizeof_multidim_arrays(){
    string animals[][3] = {
        {"fox", "dog", "cat"},
        {"mouse", "squirrel", "parrot"}
    };
    int rows =  sizeof (animals) / sizeof (animals[0]);
    int cols = sizeof (animals[0]) / sizeof (string);
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
            cout << animals[i][j] << " " << flush;
        }
        cout << endl;    
    }
}
```

Output:

```
fox dog cat 
mouse squirrel parrot
```